# Obtain Polar Coordinate from specific origin

Tags: c++, coordinates, polar-coordinates

Let's say I have a list of points represented in cartesian coordinates (Ex. (x,y)). I'm trying to grab one of those points, and make it the origin of a polar plane, and get the polar coordinates of all of the other points.

Right now I have this:

**This is my point struct**

```cpp
struct point
{

    float x;
    float y;
    string type;
    float toDegrees = (180/3.1416);

    point(float x, float y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }

    void makePolar()
    {
        float oldX = this->x;
        float oldY = this->y;
        this->x = sqrt(pow(oldX, 2) + pow(oldY, 2));
        this->y = atan(oldY/oldX) * toDegrees;
        if (this->y < 0)
        {
            this->y = 360 + this->y;
        }
    }
};
```

**And here is where I'm trying to do what I just explained**

```cpp
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < points.size(); j++)
        {
            point temp = points[j];
            if (points[i].x != points[j].x && points[i].y != points[j].y)
            {
                temp.x += points[i].x;
                temp.y += points[i].y;
                temp.makePolar();
            }
        }
    }
```

In this snippet, "points" is a vector<point>.

Comment: When your origin is non-zero, then all you need to do is transform all the points by subtracting your origin.  Then do the calculations as usual.  Conceptually, this moves your "origin" to (0,0) and moves all other points by the same amount.

Comment: Okay, so from what you are saying changing ```temp+= points[i].x``` to ```temp-= points[i].x``` and so on, will do the trick?

Comment: The fact you are using the `x` and `y` coordinates of a `point` to hold the cartesian coordinates and (on calling `makePolor()`) the polar coordinates is a good way to confuse yourself.   What do you expect to happen if you call `makePolar()` twice on the same object.

Comment: Well yes, I'm saying that, but it's super weird that you're doing this with nested loops.  The first time you run the inner loop, it'll transform all points to polar except the first one.  But then you go ahead and do that operation on all other points.

Comment: I have it so when you call this twice, it throws an error. You are right in the sense It can cause confusion, and maybe I should change it, but for know I just need to fix this.

Comment: What's your question? It's completely unclear to me.

Comment: Hello @zkoza! My question was how to convert cartesian coordinates to polar with the center being another point. Peter and paddy already helped me figure this out. I'm sorry about phrasing my question this way, I'll try to clarify more next time!

Comment: What you're trying to do is to commit software suicide. How will you know if your struct represent coordinates in polar or Cartesian coordinates? You'd have to replace it with a class, with public interface, plus a filed that informs whether the object is in Cartesian or polar coords; or simply add 2 fields for the angle and radius besides x and y. `toDegrees` would be happier if `const static` or replaced with a function. And so on and so on. Never mind, C++ requires >= 10 years to learn :-) don't give up.